# xamarin.ios Scrollview and Editor Scrolling Editor

Tags: xamarin.ios, scrollview, editor

in my App I have an Editor inside ScrollView.
If the text ist larger than Editor height, I want to be able to scroll the Editor without clicking inside the Editor.
I have a CustomRenderer for Editor and ScollView, but which Settings are possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let **Editor** scroll to bottom automatically, you can use the following code in your **EditorRenderer**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
  base.OnElementChanged(e);

  if(Control!=null)
  {
     Control.LayoutManager.AllowsNonContiguousLayout = false;
     Control.ScrollRangeToVisible(new NSRange(Control.Text.Length-1,1));
  }

}
```